# Pass a string value as parameter in Url.action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website using `asp.net mvc 4` & `EF6`. I want to pass a string value as a parameter in a `Url.action` link. However, whenever I click on the link I get this error:

> The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 76.

This is the code that creates it:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(string EditId)
{
    if (Session["username"] != null)
    {
        UserInfo uinfo = db.UserInfoes.Find(EditId);
        return View(uinfo);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("HomeIndex");
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<a class="btn btn-info" 
 href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { EditId = item.regno.ToString() })"><b>Edit</b></a>
```

How can I use a string value as a parameter?

Comment: Is item.regno an integer?

Comment: No, it's as an varchar.

Comment: And what data type is the primary key of your entity UserInfo?

Comment: The problem is not the actionlink, it is that you are passing a varchar to the .Find() method as the key to search on, when it is expecting an integer.

Comment: Tnx. So what should I need to use instead of `.Find()`?

Comment: But my value is string, because its in `varchar` format.

Comment: The error disagrees. `Find` uses the primary key of the entity which I suspect is an integer. Remove `ToString()` from the action and change the Edit action's parameter to an int

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Edit(string EditId)
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {
            int id;
            //Check try to parse the string into an int if it fails it will return false if it was parsed it will return true
            bool result = Int32.TryParse(EditId, out id);
            if (result)
            {                    
                 //I wouldn't use find unless you're 100% sure that record will always be there.
                 //This will return null if it cannot find your userinfo with that ID
                 UserInfo uinfo = db.UserInfoes.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == id);      
                 //Check for null userInfo    
            return View(uinfo);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("HomeIndex");
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) always uses the primary key. There is no need to use `FirstOrDefault`. Moreover, a failure to parse the key in an Edit action should fails sounding alarms, not silently redirect.

Comment: Your first point is noted but the second point should be commented to the question above since the code your commenting on belongs to asker